# Excel VBA date copying different for no apparent reason?

Tags: excel, vba

Simple task with confusing alternate results.

I'm copying a range of data using:

```
WS.Range("A2:Z" & lRow).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("A2:Z" & lRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

The first column from the copy sheet is a date in format `12/05/2017  01:00:00` (note the double space in between date and time)

In one instance of this the date values are pasted across fine and come out as dates - great!

In another instance of this the date values are pasted but come out as `14/05/2017 01:00` and these aren't registering as dates, rather as a text string.

I noticed I could go through the dates cell by cell and press enter which converted them to dates, so I tried using `.range("A1:A100").value = .range("A1:A100").value` to no avail.

I suspect it may have something to do with the day-month-year format as opposed to being month-day-year (since it works for a sheet that starts on 12-may but not on 14-may) but (1) could there be another difference, (2) why does pressing ENTER work fine and (3) how can I emulate pressing ENTER on my whole range of cells (bearing in mind .value = .value doesn't work)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are your regional settings on your PC set to for short/long date?

Comment: Short date is set as dd/MM/yyyy and the long date is set as  dd MMMM yyyy

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** Type conversion (fixing the values before they cause trouble on your worksheet in the first place) is absolutely the best way to go.

**In long:**

Let's start with these two values:

```
22.05.2017 12:00
22.05.2017  12:00
```

I'll place the first in `A1` and the second in `B1`. Note that Excel will often try to do the type conversion, so in this case I'll manually enforce `A1` to contain text values by formatting the cell as such after-the-fact.

Let's verify:
[image]

Using the Immediate window, we can see that the compiler recognizes the content of `A1` as a pure text value, while it recognizes the content in `B1` as a date value.

**The solution you need is to ensure that any text values are converted to date values:**

```
Option Base 1

Sub pasteTextAsDate()
    Dim dateArr As Variant
    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A3")

    ' In the line below, we fill the variant variable with the content of the range, casting the variable into an array of variants
    dateArr = rng

    ' For the sake of proving this code works, we'll start by printing the content and what type it is
    For Each s In dateArr
        Debug.Print s & " - " & TypeName(s)
    Next s

    For i = 1 To UBound(dateArr)
        ' This is where we loop through the array and cast any string values to date values
        dateArr(i, 1) = CDate(dateArr(i, 1))

        ' Here we verify for ourselves that the conversions are OK
        Debug.Print dateArr(i, 1) & " - " & TypeName(dateArr(i, 1))
    Next i

    ' And here we print the result to the worksheet
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C1:C3").Value = dateArr
End Sub
```

Result:  [image]

Comment: Thank you for such a wholesome and succinct answer! I will apply this to my sheets over the weekend and see how it rolls but this looks a very promising approach.